# Excel to Database. Help on table design

Tags: database

This is my excel spreadsheet and I am trying to convert it to a proper database. Dry and Sensors are products/goods. I like to build a database that is flexible to add more products. Also their attributes like 'type' and 'kV' can hold multiple values.

### [image: Excel Columns]

I am not experience with designing databases. My current design is

```
    table_company
       company_id
       company_name
       etch...
    table_dry_ctd_type
       company_id
       record_id
       dry_ctd_type
    table_dry_vtd_kV
       company_id
       record_id
       dry_vtd_kV

       I ended up with 13 tables.
```

business rule (if needed):

-company can have 0 to many products

-products can have 0 to many sub categories.

-product type and KV can hold multiple values.

-Type is not required to have kV

Comment: Why dont you plan to use Cassandra as you underlying database. That will provide you lot of flexibility in defining the number of rows and columns on the fly.

Comment: @AngelsandDemons, Cassandra is tough to use, and he is not asking for massive performance or uptime.

Comment: what do you mean by "product type and KV can hold multiple values"? e.g. CTD can have type 'a', 'b', 'c' AND kV 'aX', 'bX', 'cX', or any number of types with any number of KVs? may also a type which has no KV or vice versa? are these type/KV combos repeating or something "user defined" so pretty much randomly anything? "sub categories" is CTD, VTD, and so on on the above example, right?

Comment: yes. for example each company has different types CTD. Company1 has typeA and Company2 has type B. Some company may have 2 types and some companies have none. Each type has a corresponding KV. They are define d by any user inputs and not static.

Comment: @JakeMogra OK, but if comp1 has typeA with a KV of 10, and comp27 also has a typeA, is their KV 10 too, or can be anything? so are types related to their KVs? ie if type = A, KV must be 10 (or "10 or 20"?), but nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you gave I'd create -sort of- the following 3 tables:

- company data
- product types (fields: `[uniqueID]`; `ptID`; `pName`; `pSubName`; `subPType`) so data is:
  1, 1, "DRY", `NULL`, `NULL` *(`pSubName` NULL == Product Type "definition" field)*
  2, 1, "DRY", "CTD", `???` --*whatever 'type' field's value is*
  3, 1, "DRY", "VTD", `???`
  , 
  ...
  6, 2, "Sensors", "VCS", `???`
  *If you need to get data several times based on product sub-type, also add a `ptSubID` -numeric- field and get data based on that*
- data table storing `companyID`, `productTypeUniqueID`, `KV` and e.g. `amount` or other "value data" you may or may not have
  *If added `productTypeUniqueID` to product type table, add that here too!*

Adding new company, product type or product sub-type is obvious. Getting data would look something like:

```
SELECT CMP.compName AS 'Company Name',PRD.pname AS 'Product',PRD.pSubName AS 'subProduct',PRD.pType AS 'Type',DTA.KV AS 'KV', DTA.amount
FROM data_table AS DTA
     LEFT OUTER JOIN company_table AS CMP ON CMP.compID=DTA.compID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN product_table AS PRD ON (PRD.ptID=DTA.ptID [AND PRD.ptSubID=DTA.ptSubID])
WHERE PRD.ptID=1 --all "DRY" products
/** or: **/ WHERE (PRD.ptID=1 AND PRD.ptSubID<>2) AND CMP.compID=8
```

But it may vary based on:

- Most common data retrieval types will be used
- Details you didn't share but important search keywords (e.g. sub-products' dimensions)
- Frequency of product updates/changes, product type/sub-type updates/changes
- Typical changes may come -based on business experience-, such as "we don't use product sub-types anymore"

Hope this helps!

Comment: @JakeMogra if you think this is the answer you was looking for I'd appreciate you marking this as the answer. Thanks in adavance!